# How to use createParentPath as a parameter for mv ? - express.js

Tags: file, express, server

I'm uploading a file to an Express server using the "mv" function:

```
file.mv( 'directory/directory/director' , createParentPath:true ,(err) => {
if (err) {
  return res.status(500).send(err);
}
});
```

I use the `createParentPath:true` argument there so that if the directory doesn't exit, it creates that! But I guess that's not the way to use the argument.

It's showing an error:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

How should i use this argument to create the directory if it doesn't exist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) middleware.

The configuration option `createParentPath` is not meant to be passed to the `mv` method of a file object, but is a config option for initializing the middleware.

Example:

```
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const app = express();

app.use(fileUpload({
    // configure middleware to create parent directories
    createParentPath: true
}));

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    let file = req.files.sampleFile;

    file.mv( 'directory/directory/director' , (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
    });
});
```